# How to store unicode characters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, unicode

In SQL Server, I am trying to create a table that can store unicode characters. Specifically this one

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0144/index.htm

However if I pick `nvarchar` as the column type, then store it and then select it, it shows as a regular `n`.

How can I get it to store properly?

Comment: Make sure the column type is `NVARCHAR([length])` and if you are inserting strings, prefix them with `N'mystring'` so that it knows they're unicode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works fine

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
InputChar NVARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @t (InputChar)
VALUES (N'ń')

INSERT INTO @t (InputChar)
VALUES ('ń')

SELECT * FROM @t
```

[image: Uniode Results]

Are you making sure that when you inserting your strings you are specifying that the string is unicode ? e.g.`N'yourstring'`